# How to stop MetaTrader Terminal 4 [MT4] offline chart from updating the prices

Tags: mql4, metatrader4, mt4

How do I stop <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal 4</kbd> offline chart from updating the price on its own?

I want to update the price on my own because of the difference in timezone with my broker. I have checked all the properties and the `MQL4` forum. No luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### For truly offline-charts, there is a way

While regular charts process an independent event-flow, received from MT4-Server, there is a change for retaining your own control over `TOHLCV`-data records -- including the `TimeZone` shifts, synthetic `Bar`(s) additions and other adaptations, as needed.

You may create your own, transformed, `TOHLCV`-history and import these records via <kbd>**`F2`**</kbd> facility, called in MT4 a <kbd>History Centre</kbd>.

[image]

### How to avoid a live-quote-stream updates in <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal 4</kbd>

The simplest ever way is not to login to any Trading Server. This will avoid unwanted updates from reaching your local `anFxQuoteStreamPROCESSOR`.

There used to be a way, how to inject fake `QuoteStreamDATA` into a local `MT4`, however this enters a gray, if not black zone, as MetaQuotes, Inc., postulated the Server/Terminal protocol to be a protected IP and any attempt to reverse-engineer they consider an unlawfull violation of their rights and could cause legal consequences, so be carefull on stepping there. Anyway, a doable approach with an explicit risk warning being presented above.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. Quotes get fed in from mt4 and get "evented" into the metatrader.